# Continuity of a set-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, optimization, continuity, set-valued-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a set-valued
function defined by
\begin{equation*}
f\left( x\right) =\left\{ y\in \mathbb{R}^{m}:g\left( x\right) +h\left(
x\right) ^{T}y\leq 0\right\} \text{,}
\end{equation*}
where $g:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $h:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow 
\mathbb{R}^{m}$ are continuous functions. How do you show that $f$ is
continuous in $\mathbb{R}^{n}\diagdown\left\{  0\right\}  $?

Comment: What's your definition of continuity of a set-valued function? And what have you tried?

Comment: Answered on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443471/on-the-continuity-of-a-set-valued-function-correspondence